# xmlrpc attack on nginx configured with HTTPS redirection

Tags: nginx, xml-rpc

I am trying to avoid nasty xmlrpc attack with the following configuration:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl default deferred;
   server_name myserver.com;

   ...
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myserver.com;

  location /xmlrpc.php {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        return 444;
  }

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Apparently the location block is not working, since requests to /xmlrpc.php get redirected as showed by the logs:

```
[02/Jun/2016:11:24:10 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

How can I discard all requests to `/xmlrpc.php` right away without having them redirected to HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

XMLRPC attack is a common attack that lets an attacker constantly calls your xmlrpc.php file with random authentication credentials.

You need to use utilities like Fail2Ban which is quite effective in banning and preventing your WordPress site against common xmlrpc attack.

First of all disable XMLRPC if you are not posting content from outside. Add the following line of code in your theme's `function.php` file

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

Add the following in your `.conf` file

```
location = /xmlrpc.php {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

Then, you need to install `Fail2Ban` on your server

```
apt-get install fail2ban iptables
```

or

```
yum install fail2ban
```

Post installation, you need to edit jail.conf file

```
vim /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
```

Inside the `jail.conf` file add the following lines of code

```
[xmlrpc]
enabled = true
filter = xmlrpc
action = iptables[name=xmlrpc, port=http, protocol=tcp]
logpath = /var/log/apache2/access.log 
bantime = 43600
maxretry = 2
```

This will read the access.log file (provide actual path of your access log) and looks for failed attempts. If it detects more than 2 failed attempts, the attackers IP address is added in your iptables.

Now, we have to create a filter for fail2ban. Type this in terminal

```
cd /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/
vim xmlrpc.conf
```

Inside this filter file paste the following definition

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .*POST .*xmlrpc\.php.*
ignoreregex =
```

Now, just restart the fail2ban service

```
service fail2ban restart or /etc/init.d/fail2ban/restart
```

See the log like this

```
tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log
```

Also in your iptables you will constantly see lots of entries which must be seeing connection refused error.

```
watch iptables -L
```

to constantly monitor. It should immediately block xmlrpc attack and you should see lots of entries in your iptables.

If there are plugins which depends on XMLRPC, you can allow your own IP in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it that way:

```
location ^~/xmlrpc.php {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: What's the 444 response? I can't find any docs for it

Comment: It tells NGINX to close the connection without sending a response, basically it's the HTTP equivalent of the middle finger :-)